# what to learn to complete RSS Application of iPhone

Tags: objective-c, iphone

I am beggainer developer of iphone application so far i have develope a single iphone application which is not so bad [Click here](http://www.screencast.com/users/GloboSoft/folders/Jing/media/7af1f42c-9dea-49f0-873a-00fade4aa48b)

now I am developing iphone application for a website which is Clone of youtube.
i have done the following task so far.
   videos are displayed in three categories i.e Latest,all,Feature with the help of RSS Parser i.e TouchUp Xml.
   all videos are running in UIWebView.

Know I want to put these features.

```
  1:User write comments on any video from application.

  2:USer signe up login from application.

  3:user Rate video from application
```

any idea what i should learn to talk with my database which is on server side.

Thanks in advance and sorry for my Bad english. :)

Comment: Please do not post links to your own applications.

Comment: Is it considered advertising?

Comment: AS my next application is almost same to first one that why i have done it sorry................ 
as i am new so don't know how to post what to post and what not to post.......

Answer (score 0):

If you make a REST API to your server application, mainly you need to know how to use NSURLConnection and related classes.  There are many open-source Objective-C REST wrappers to look at -- for example, the StackExchange one:

https://stackapps.com/questions/346/stackkit-an-api-framework-for-cocoa

Here's Google's data API for Cocoa

http://code.google.com/p/gdata-objectivec-client/wiki/GDataObjCIntroduction